# Formula to calculate power from a solar panel?

Tags: power, solar-energy, formula-derivation

I am currently working on a project that works with solar panels on Mars and I am trying to calculate how much power I would get from a solar panel on the surface. I have values such as solar irradiance, the area of the solar panel, and the efficiency of the panel. I found one formula: Power=area x efficiency x solar irradiance x performance ratio

However, I cannot find a standard value for performance ratio anywhere and I don't have a reliable source on this equation either, so I can't use it on a paper.

So, does anyone know formula out there that allows me to calculate the power delivered from a solar panel? If so, I would greatly appreciate it and if there is a reliable source (like scholarly paper), please leave a name for that as well.

Comment: Where did you find that formula - please provide a link to that document.

Comment: Same comment I made: Check out books like Duffie & Beckman Solar Thermal Engineering for the question you posted here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/147459/72855

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *Sustainable Energy, without the hot air*, Prof. David Mackay, ISBN 9780954452933.  It's also on the web.  http://www.withouthotair.com

He says:

> Typical solar
>   panels have an efficiency of about 10%; expensive ones perform at 20%.
>   (Fundamental physical laws limit the efficiency of photovoltaic systems to
>   at best 60% with perfect concentrating mirrors or lenses, and 45% without
>   concentration. A mass-produced device with efficiency greater than 30%
>   would be quite remarkable.) The average power delivered by south-facing
>   20%-efficient photovoltaic panels in Britain would be
>
> 20% × 110 W/m<sup>2</sup> = 22 W/m<sup>2</sup>.

http://www.withouthotair.com/c6/page_39.shtml

The 110 W/m<sup>2</sup> is derived on the previous page, for a average south-facing roof in Britain: raw energy = 1,000 W/m<sup>2</sup>, with a correction of 32% for orientation and 34% for cloud = 108.8 W/m<sup>2</sup>.  Tracking systems, non-Earth locations, no cloud would affect all of these.

There are many references in this book for you to follow up.  Wikipedia page [Solar Cell Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell_efficiency) also has several dozen references.